# Function called for all NSWindow

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos

When I call function, it's called for all window opened and not just for the selected window.

If the function is called by `@IBAction` It's applied for the selected window. Otherwhise, it's applied for all windows.
How can i call the function just for the current selected window ?

Here is an preview:
[image]

This is the minimal reproductible code:

```
//  AppDelegate.swift

import Cocoa

@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @objc func openMyWindow()
        {
            let storyboard:NSStoryboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            guard let controller:NSWindowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "WindowMain") as? NSWindowController else { return }
            controller.showWindow(self)
        }
    
    @objc func test()
        {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "TEST"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
        }
    
    func applicationDockMenu(_ sender: NSApplication) -> NSMenu? {
        
        let dockMenu = NSMenu()
        dockMenu.addItem(withTitle: "New window", action: #selector(openMyWindow), keyEquivalent:     "")
        dockMenu.addItem(withTitle: "test", action: #selector(test), keyEquivalent:     "")
        return dockMenu
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    func applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState(_ app: NSApplication) -> Bool {
        return true
    }


}
```

```
//  ViewController.swift

import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    @objc func Test(){
        
        TextView.string = "It's applied for ALL views -> it's NOT ok"
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
        
        TextView.string = "It's applied just for this view -> it's ok"
    }
    
    @IBOutlet var TextView: NSTextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(Test), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "TEST"), object: nil)
  
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notification with object nil (no object) are hard to distinguish when it is not even evaluated which of the windows invoked the post.

In other words, make use of the `object:` parameter when you post the Notification.

Otherwise all registered observers in multiple windows will act on one and the same Notification.

So what object could be used to know who was sending?
The window object itself of course.

Your WindowController has a window it belongs to as well, just compare its address to the posted Notifications object and act when they are the same.
Or compare against the front most windows address, which usually is the window the user expects to act on commands given.

Answer (score 0):

If the target of the menu item isn't set then the action message is sent to the first responder. In your view the text view is the first responder but it doesn't handle the `test` message and sends it to the next responder. The view controller is in the responder chain and will receive the `test` message.
Set the selector of the menu item to the action of the view controller and the view controller of the front window will receive it. No notifications required.

```
//  AppDelegate.swift

import Cocoa

@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    @objc func openMyWindow() {
        let storyboard:NSStoryboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        guard let controller:NSWindowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "WindowMain") as? NSWindowController else { return }
        controller.showWindow(self)
    }

    func applicationDockMenu(_ sender: NSApplication) -> NSMenu? {
        let dockMenu = NSMenu()
        dockMenu.addItem(withTitle: "New window", action: #selector(openMyWindow), keyEquivalent:     "")
        dockMenu.addItem(withTitle: "test", action: #selector(ViewController.test), keyEquivalent: "")
        return dockMenu
    }

}
```

```
//  ViewController.swift

import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    @objc func test() {
        TextView.string = "It's applied for this view -> it's now ok"
    }
    
    @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
        TextView.string = "It's applied just for this view -> it's ok"
    }
    
    @IBOutlet var TextView: NSTextView!
    
}
```